# C# TLS and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssl, tls1.2

I recently had to update my secure web server to remove TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 leaving just TLS 1.2. This ended up causing the connection to the SQL server to fail (I know an update to the SQL server needs to be performed to accept TLS1.2)

What I don't understand is my connection string does not contain "TrustServerCertificate" so I don't understand why the connection between the web server and the SQL server is running through a SSL connection when it is not specified there. Is this by default once the site on the Web Server has a Secure Certificate installed? Or is there something else that is enforcing the secure connection.

Comment: I don't have much idea about networking.Here is how i understand it.Think of this connection between two clients,when one initiates a ssl connection,other can't refuse it because it is not using ssl.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have "force encryption" enabled on your SQL Server instance.

Comment: Unless you know of a way to query that I couldn't say. the only access I have to the server is through Visual Studios. Yeah kind of crappy I don't even have SSMS